# how to define an instance in a list comprehension and use it

Tags: python-3.x

So I originally have coded in the following:

```
files_in_dir = [f for f in os.listdir(out_path) if (
            os.path.isfile(os.path.join(out_path, f))
            and
            '.txt' in f
            and
            not Parser(f).is_a
            and
            not Parser(f).is_b
        )]
```

the code reviewer says I shouldn't instantize Parser object twice, so I should do f_parser = Parser(f) and f_parser.is_a

how do I do this in list comprehension?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

someone helped me in my group and it worked

```
files_in_dir = [f for f in os.listdir(out_path) if (
            os.path.isfile(os.path.join(out_path, f))
            and
            '.txt' in f
            and
            (lambda parser: parser.is_a
            and
            parser.is_b)(Parser(f))
        )]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using at least Python 3.8, you can use the [walrus operator (`:=`)](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/#simplifying-list-comprehensions) to assign the parser instance to a local variable:

```py
files_in_dir = [
    f for f in os.listdir(out_path) if (
        os.path.isfile(os.path.join(out_path, f))
        and '.txt' in f
        and not (p := Parser(f)).is_a
        and not p.is_b
    )
]
```

If you're not on at least 3.8, you'll have to use a local helper, like:

```py
def is_valid_file(f):
  if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(out_path, f)) and '.txt' in f:
    p = Parser(f)
    return not p.is_a and not p.is_b
  else:
    return False

files_in_dir = [
    f for f in os.listdir(out_path) if is_valid_file(f)
]
```

Comment: anything for 3.6.5?

Comment: You can't do this inside the comprehension in 3.6. I updated my answer with another option.

Comment: thank you, someone actually helped me in my group to use lambda function, I will post it for my self answer too